# Django Authorization Checking in URL having wild card pattern

Tags: django, spring-boot, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I am trying to implement permission checking mechanism in URLs for a request using wildcard techniques, rather than implement permission checking on each views.

Currently What I have is.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', include('admin_urls.py')),
    ...
]
```

and my `admin_urls.py` is as follows

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ViewSpaceIndex.as_view(), name="admin_index"),
     path('', EmployeeView.as_view(), name="employee"),
    ...
]
```

and views are as follows

```
@method_decorator(admin_required, name='dispatch')
 class EmployeeView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'secret.html'



@method_decorator(admin_required, name='dispatch')
 class EmployeeView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'secret.html'
```

What I want to achieve is without using the repeated `@method_decorator(admin_required, name='dispatch')` decorator in every view I want to apply the permission to a wild
card URLs '/admin/**' with `admin_required` permission like in Spring boot as follows.

```
  http.authorizeRequests()
           
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").has_permission("is_admin")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your project root url like this:

```
from .my_custom_decorators import admin_required
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin_required(include('admin_urls.py'))),
    ...
]
```

I don't know this will work or not but you can try.